# .HTACCESS rewriting a url the basic

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have 2 questions regarding .htaccess,

1- if i use .htaccess to rewrite the url's on my website does it affect any of the requests or do i need to change the link for all forms for example if a action post for a form is index.php?submit do i need to change that link ? when i for example hide .php extension in .htaccess or it doesn't affect it

2-how do i basically hide all .php extensions

3- if i have the below url 

www.link.com/post.php?post_id=53&post_name=the-International-day-in-roma

how do i make .htaccess rewrite it to the following
www.link.com/post/the-International-day-in-roma

does it matter if there was commas or can we remove them also ?
www.link.com/post.php?post_id=53&post_name=everyday,-or-today,-or-tomorrow

Answer (score -1):

you can hide php file name in htaccess 
for example if someone click this link

```
www.link.com/post/the-International-day-in-roma/
```

htaccess file contverts the url to post.php and call the the post name by `$1`
 it represents this part "`/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/`" the it is dynamic  and it can be changed !

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^post/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ post.php?post_id=53&post_name=$1 [L]
```